# Creating new bulk views operations (VBO) actions for custom entity types

Tags: 7, entities, views

I have the following code and created a view for my custom entity type. I just want to create a new action button to be able to change a field's text to something else. I'm not sure why this custom action isn't showing up. Under which window am I suppose to see it? *Execute arbitary php* or *modify multiple entity values*?

Where is a good example code of getting a custom action working? Is there a pre-built VBO action example I can just download to see how it's made?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_action_info().
 */
function rubik_custom_action_info() {
  return array(
    'hideit' => array(
      'type' => 'entity',
      'label' => t('Custom Action'),
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'triggers' => array('any'),
      'behavior' => array('changes_property'),
      'vbo_configurable' => FALSE,
      'pass rows' => TRUE,
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Action function for MY_ACTION_NAME.
 */
function hideit(&$entity, $context = array()) {
  drupal_set_message('ok it works');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several VBO examples within the VBO module itself. Take for instance delete.action.inc which allows you to delete any entity. I can't see anything explicitly wrong with your code, but I'd highly recommend you follow convention and rework it to look like the other `hook_action_info()` implementations:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_action_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_action_info() {
  $actions['MYMODULE_custom_action'] = array(
    'type' => 'node', // Here come's the name of your custom entity type
    'label' => t('Custom Action'),
    'configurable' => FALSE,
    'triggers' => array('any'),
    'behavior' => array('changes_property'),
    'vbo_configurable' => FALSE,
    'pass rows' => TRUE,
  );

  return $actions;
}

function MYMODULE_custom_action($entity, $context) {
  // Your action here.
}
```

Your function name is `rubik_custom_action_info`. You aren't trying to define this within a theme are you? Don't do that. Put it in a separate module. Themes are no place for this.

Another module that may be of help is the [Commerce Bundle Helper sandbox](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/nvahalik/2575161). Not only does it declare VBO actions, but it shows how you can automatically add it into a View that already exists by altering the VBO configuration.

Answer (score 4):

After your action has been defined, it can be added in the Views UI under **Selected Bulk Operations** in your *Bulk operations* field settings. It will be a separate checkbox ***alongside*** other actions like *Execute arbitrary PHP script*, etc. Once selected, it should show up as select option or action button (depending on how the VBO field is configured).

The [VBO development guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052067) on d.o. is a good example of working code for defining an action, adding a optional global/per-bulk setting form, & creating action handler.

Here's a very bare bones example:

```
//Will add a "User Action" option to Bulk Operations: User field in Views UI
function MYMODULE_action_info() {
  return array(
    'MYMODULE_user_action' => array(
      //Can be other entities used in a view (e.g. 'node')
      'type' => 'user',              
      'label' => t('User Action'),
      'behavior' => array('changes_property'),
      'triggers' => array('any'),

      //Set to true if you an intermediate options form for your action
      //'configurable' => true,      

      //Set to true if you want additional globaloptions
      //'vbo_configurable' => true,
    ),
  );
}

function MYMODULE_user_action(&$entity, $context){
  //$entity is the current entity being modified; it can
  //  modified directly to perform the action on the entity

  //$context is an array of contextual information about the 
  //  current state of bulk processing  (e.g. items remaining) 
  //  It also contains configurable options values if any were set (see below)
}

//If 'configurable' => true in hook_action_info() item this trio of functions 
// will add/process an intermediate form just like any Drupal form
function MYMODULE_user_action($settings, &$form_state){
 //$settings['settings'] will contains settings set in 
 //  MYMODULE_user_action_views_bulk_operations_form
}
function MYMODULE_user_action_validate($form, $form_state) {
}
function MYMODULE_user_action_submit($form, $form_state) {
  //return an array of values usable by MYMODULE_user_action
}

//If 'vbo_configurable' => true, in hook_action_info() this presents 
// additional configurable options for the  VBO action. 
// It returns a Drupal form array
function MYMODULE_user_action_views_bulk_operations_form($options) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the implementation of `hook_action_info()`, you need to write the name of your custom entity type, instead of just `entity`. For example; `node`, `user`, `comment`, `taxonomy_term`, `field_collection_item` etc. The action will be available as long as the base table for your view mathces the type of the given entity in `hook_action_info()`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_action_info().
 */
function rubik_custom_action_info() {
  return array(
    'hideit' => array(
      'type' => 'node', // Here come's the name of your custom entity type
      'label' => t('Custom Action'),
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'triggers' => array('any'),
      'behavior' => array('changes_property'),
      'vbo_configurable' => FALSE,
      'pass rows' => TRUE,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Took some time to figure this out, but its working. I have a custom entity called office and I needed to create a new vbo visible toggle button.

I put this code in the custom office module. Originally I put it in the theme template.php file to test, but it didn't work for some reason as I'm guessing it fires too late in the drupal boot process.

```
/**
* Views Bulk Operation Custom Visible Toggle Button
*/
function office_action_info() {  //office was my module name
  return array(
    'action_off' => array(  //name of your function call
      'type' => 'entity',  //targets all entities on the site
      'label' => t('Toggle Visible'),
      'configurable' => FALSE,
      'behavior' => array('changes_property'),  //set the behavior type
      'triggers' => array('any'),
    ),
  );
}

function action_off($entity, $context = array()) {

  //Populate the variable using entity_load of the associated id.
  $eload = entity_load('office', array($entity->office_id));

  //Changes the field value for the entity. In this case its the Visible field
  $eload[$entity->office_id]->visible = ($eload[$entity->office_id]->visible == 1 ? 0 : 1);

  //After editing the entity array, save it. Used current() to get 1st result.
  entity_save('office', current($eload));

  //not exactly sure what this does, but its to clear the entity cache?
  entity_get_controller('office')->resetCache(array($entity->office_id)); 
}
```

[image]